# Unable to create/modify sqlite tables from Java application

Tags: java, database, eclipse, sqlite

I have a basic java application and a sqlite DB. 
I can create table manually through sqLite browser. And I am able to access these tables from my JAVA application.

E.g. Reading from existing table: (I have omitted the try catch blocks in the sample below just to reduce the length of question)

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;

String query = "select * from test1 where uname = ? and name = user1";
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStatement.setString(1, "test"); 
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();           

if(resultSet.next())
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

I am able to perform this query successfully.

However, if I create / modify a table, changes does not show up in SQlite DB (I am viewing db in sqLite browser). If I copy paste the same query in SQlite browser, the query runs successfully and a row is added.

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;

String query = "INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE) VALUES (3, 'tOM', 32);";

preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query); 
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Am I missing something?

EDIT: Both the above tables exist in my sqlite db. Both were created through sqlite browser

EDIT2: I was getting true from my example 1 above, that's why I felt that I am able to read from db. I update my code to print the data read and nothing gets printed which means I am not able to read the data as well:

```
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test1");
```

and

```
private static void outputResultSet(ResultSet rs) throws Exception {
        ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 1; i < numberOfColumns + 1; i++) {
          String columnName = rsMetaData.getColumnName(i);
          System.out.print(columnName + "   ");

        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("----------------------");

        while (rs.next()) {
          for (int i = 1; i < numberOfColumns + 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(rs.getString(i) + "   ");
          }
          System.out.println();
        }

      }
```

The connection string is:

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\akshay\\sqlite_test.sqlite");
conn.setAutoCommit(true);
return conn;
```

Comment: Does the user your are using to connect to the database have the correct permissions to update the database/table? Are you connecting to the same database (don't laugh, I spent a day with a similar problem and it turned out I was connecting to the wrong database). Do you have autocommit enabled? If not, are you committing the transaction?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am able to read the tables so I am connecting to the correct DB. Let me verify the autocommit part.

Comment: So I assume if you update the database in the browser, that shows up in program?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have set the autocommit to true, but still I am unable to make it work. Do I need to do something like begin transaction and end transaction?

Comment: How you handle exceptions in this code?

Comment: Can you share your connection string. Also, are you updating the database which is a file in disk or embedded within the jar/program?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I guess my problem is bigger. I have updated the question under EDIT2 section. Can you please have a look? I think I am not able to read data as well. I thought I am able to read because I was getting my if condition true in the first example.

Comment: I rebooted everything. From eclipse to sqLite browser and even my system. And everything has started working correctly. I am unable to comprehend what was stuck that rebooting fixed. Sigh!